# Prime Factorization

Tags: python, python-3.x, prime-factoring

So my program is supposed to find the prime factors of an integer and then the contents of the integer array is printed out and the values in the array are supposed to be multiplied together (giving you the original number) 
this is what it is supposed to look like

Prime Factorization Program

```
Enter an integer > 1: 210 

Prime Factors 
2
3
5
7
Check Product = 210
```

this is my code and my results

```
def main():
    a = [0]*20
    print("Prime Factorization Program")
    print()
    num = eval(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))
    count = 0
    for k in range(1,num):
        if num % k == 0:
            a[count]= k
            count = count + 1

    mySum = 0
    for k in range(count):
        mySum = mySum + a[k]
    print()
    print("Prime Factors")
    for k in range(count):
        print(a[k])
    print("Check Product =",mySum)

main()
```

here are my result

Prime Factorization Program

```
Enter an integer > 1: 210

Prime Factors
1
2
3
5
6
7
10
14
15
21
30
35
42
70
105
Check Product = 366
```

Comment: Why do you think multiplying all the factors of a number will return the number?

Comment: you need to find the **prime** factors, not all factors.

Comment: `if num % k == 0:` what makes you think `k` is a prime?'

Comment: `"Check Product =",mySum` that's not a product

Comment: You're not checking if your factors are prime numbers. So you're finding all the factors, not just prime factors.

Comment: I know but I do not know how to find just the prime factors

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Why do you use `eval` on your `input`? If you need to convert the input to an int you should convert it like `int(input("Enter an integer > 1: "))`. `eval` interpret a string as code, which is most likely not what you want. It could be used for evil if someone else were to use your program.

Comment: Note that you're not multiplying the factors: you're *adding* them.  This will help you find a perfect number, but it doesn't help validiate prime factorization.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Problem** - If *f* is a factor, you don't want to count multiples of *f*.
   **Solution** - Once you identify a factor *f*, divide *n* by *f*.
   **Example** - 210 is divisible by 2; divide by 2 and thereafter process 105. That ensures you don't count any more multiples of 2 like 6 or 10. 105 is divisible by 3; divide by 3 and continue with 35.
2. **Problem** - Prime factors can show up multiple times. 12 = 2×2×3.
   **Solution** - If *f* is a factor, keep checking for it and dividing by *f* until you've accounted for all occurrences.
   **Example** - 12 is divisible by 2; divide by 2 to get 6. 6 is still divisible by 2; divide by 2 again to get 3. 3 is not divisible by 2; continue to the next factor.

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is printing all the factor instead of just prime factors. Below is the sample function you may refer for prime factorization:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    prim_facs = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            prim_facs.append(d)
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
       prim_facs.append(n)
    return prim_facs

# Sample Example
# >>> prime_factors(210)
# [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: the program will not run

Comment: I verified it and it working for me. Can you explain me why you mentioned this?

Comment: @MattPoretsky if you don't call the function of course it will not run...